# How to create a counter using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, counter

So I'm trying to create a counter using jQuery but I can't get it to work for some reason.
I'm using 3 inputs. 1 number input and 2 buttons.

My html looks like this:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="title">
            <div id="middle">
                <div id="inner">Books</div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <input class="counter" type="number" value="0"></input>

        <input class="red" type="submit" value="-"></input>
        <input class="green" type="submit" value="+"></input>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.10.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var num = 0;

    $(".red").click(function(){
        num = $(".counter").val();
        num = num - 1;
        $(".counter").val(num);
    })

    $(".green").click(function(){
        num = $(".counter").val();
        num = num + 1;
        $(".counter").val(num);
    })

}
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong with my code.

Comment: remove these: `num = $(".counter").val();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I have use `+`, which Force the engine to implicitly convert it by applying a math operator to it;

Convert input value to number

```
num = +$(".counter").val();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/MYP75/1/)

Additionally, You are missing closing `)` of document ready handler.

I would also like to suggest you should use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It worked right away when I removed the DOM ready handler. The "+" that you mentioned is actually not needed because as @JasonP mentioned the variable num already has a value of 0 stored to it and I'm only changing that variable and then outputting it.

Comment: @Rorrim, What if you input 5 in input field, Will it work if you remove `num = +$(".counter").val();` and then perform increment or decrement? I have that in consideration when providing solution

Comment: @Rorrim, Do share finding/answer of my question

Comment: It will actually start incrementing/decrementing from 0 since the variable num has 0 as a starting value. The "value" of the input with class="counter" is just for looks, it won't do anything. But I get your point, if it was actually being used I would have to do it your way in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's failing is because the `val()` is returned as a string and the `+` is doing string concatenation, not addition.

However, since you already have the value stored in a variable, you really don't need to pull the value from the input each time. Here's a simpler version:

http://jsfiddle.net/bcHWa/

```
var num = 0;

$(".red").click(function () {
    $(".counter").val(--num);
})

$(".green").click(function () {
    $(".counter").val(++num);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is weird, I tried it your way and it didn't work. 
Then I removed the $(document).ready(function(){)} and it worked. Do you have any idea why that happened? 

Also good idea on using only $(".counter").val(--num); it saves 2 lines of code!

Comment: The only way adding the dom ready handler should break it is if you are defining `num` inside the handler, then trying to access it outside the handler or from a different handler or function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Here is the counter I made btw http://juniaj.com/online/Project%20Spyros/counter/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

`num = $(".counter").val();` is going to be a string, therefore "1" + "1" = "11"

Try:

```
 num = parseInt($(".counter").val());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it going to be a string though? I mean the input "counter" has a type of "number". Doesn't that change anything.

Comment: JavaScript's variable types are not defined by HTML.